# smartface.io call a web service

Tags: smartface.io

I am using smartface.io to call a  soap web service. My code is as below.  when I call it returns a error says "Server Error" But when I call it from browser it works well.

```
var requestString =
    '' +
    '' +
    '' +
    '' +
    'admin@borapay.com' +
    'Admin@123456<>' +
    '' +
    '' +
    '';


var getRate = new SMF.Net.WebClient({
        URL : "http://172.98.72.148/borapay/WebServices/CustomerServices.asmx",
        httpMethod : "POST",
        requestHeaders : [
            "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
            "SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/UserLogin"

        ],
        onSyndicationSuccess : function (e) {

        },
        onServerError : function (e) {
            alert("onServerError");
        },
        requestString : requestString,
        responseHandling : SMF.Net.ResponseHandling.forceText,
        timeoutInterval : 120
    });

getRate.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request string seems wrong, it should be full envelope like;

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bora="http://bora-pay.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bora:UserLogin>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <bora:userName>admin@borapay.com</bora:userName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <bora:password>Admin@123456<></bora:password>
      </bora:UserLogin>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But you need to convert that as a Java Script string.